# MySQL casting of -1 returns 18446744073709551615

Tags: mysql, casting

I can't seem to find an explanation for this and I'm pretty sure that it has previously worked as expected.

```
SELECT CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Expected: 0
Result:   18446744073709551615

Has something changed, or is this a MySQL bug?

[UPDATE]
OK, I think that I found a reason why it had appeared to work before:

```
SELECT CAST(-1.0 AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
+--------------------------------+
| CAST(-1.0 AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Now, can someone please explain the difference that this causes?.. Actually, I found in the docs!

> If either operand is a floating-point value, the result is a
>   floating-point value and is not affected by the preceding rule.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(-1.0 AS UNSIGNED INT);` gives a warning (run `warnings` before to make the warnings appear): "Error (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''".

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thanks for pointing out the warning, although the warning is slightly confusing since the manual states: "In this context, DECIMAL column values are regarded as floating-point values."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html):

> MySQL supports arithmetic with both signed and unsigned 64-bit values. If you are using numeric operators (such as + or -) and one of the operands is an unsigned integer, the result is unsigned by default (see Section 11.6.1, “Arithmetic Operators”). You can override this by using the SIGNED or UNSIGNED cast operator to cast a value to a signed or unsigned 64-bit integer, respectively.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT CAST(1-2 AS UNSIGNED)
>        -> 18446744073709551615
> mysql> SELECT CAST(CAST(1-2 AS UNSIGNED) AS SIGNED);
>        -> -1
> ```

Basically, with you cast you tell `MySQL` how to treat `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. It's `-1` when signed, `18446744073709551615` when unsigned.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is exactly 2^64-1. I would not expect any other output.

Comment: & Álvaro G. Vicario: Thanks for the explanations