# Inverse Square in MySQL results convert to very large values

Tags: mysql

I am creating a SELECT query that assesses items based on the age of attached comments.

While a linear scale is effective it gives too much value to older comments and does not allow very new comments an increased value. (c.ctime is a datetime field)

```
SELECT *, (1-(DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365)) as InverseVal FROM ...
```

Which is why I wanted to use an inverse square

```
SELECT *, (1-((DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365)^2)) as InverseVal FROM ...
```

However this produces exceptionally large values for a few items. 18446744073709551615 to be exact.

The expected behaviour was sums of values from 0.99999211 down into negative values.

I know enough (because I googled it) to recognise that this is an issue with signed and unsigned values but I am at a loss as to how to compensate.

I discovered that casting -1 to unsigned int results in the number I am seeing but I am not sure how to apply this knowledge as I am not (explicitly) casting numbers. [MySQL casting of -1 returns 18446744073709551615](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050636/mysql-casting-of-1-returns-18446744073709551615)

Changing to **1.0-(...)** makes matters worse as values result from -1 down to very large negative numbers.

```
SELECT *, (1.0-((DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365)^2)) as InverseVal FROM ...
```

How can I modify my SQL to account for this? Better yet (in terms of my specific aims), is there an efficient way of equating negative as 0?

Comment: What are the min and max values for c.CTIME?

Comment: In theory the values range between now() and some datetime over the last X years. In my test case about twelve years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem starts with you using ^ as the 'power' operator - it is actually a bitwise 'XOR'. You need to use the POW function :

```
SELECT *, (1.0-POW((DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365),2)) as InverseVal FROM ......
```

but that is not an inverse square so maybe :

```
SELECT *, (1.0- 1.0 / POW((DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365),2)) as InverseVal FROM ......
```

Comment: Brilliant. I had not realised that I had been exceptionally silly (got my operator wrong). Also many thanks for spotting the inverse square issue with my maths. I am now getting far more reasonable values. Thank you.

Comment: It can be confusing when different languages use the same character for completely different purposes - your expression would have been correct in VB.

Comment: That's what we get for having too many languages doing too many things in too many different ways. Obviously, the only solution is to eliminate all languages *EXCEPT* The One True Language Which Will Serve All Uses Perfectly. Now all we have to do is identify that One True Language and we're done. OK, I've defined the parameters of the problem - my work here is done. :-)

Comment: As today is Ada Lovelace Day - then I propose the One True Language be Ada in which case the expression should be _(1-((DATEDIFF(c.ctime,CURDATE()) / 365) ** 2))_