# Mysql returning an insane "rows" results on newer version of mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm really confused with this one. Here are the 2 version of mySQL I have running, on 2 different servers:

**Old server:**

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for pc-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

**New server:**

```
root@admin:~# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

The table structure looks like (simplified the `glinks_Links` table, as there as a LOT of columns :))

```
CREATE TABLE `glinks_CatLinks` (
  `LinkID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `glinks_Links` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CustomOrder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArticleType` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkExpired` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If I run this query on the new server:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.* 
FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links 
WHERE 
    glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID 
    AND (
        glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' 
        AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes'
    ) ORDER BY Title
```

I get some stupid result:

> Your query returned 18446744073709551615 rows.

..yet if I specify a field to grab, I get the correct rows I would expect:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.ID FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title

Your query returned 10 rows.

+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 88  |
| 166 |
| 187 |
| 87  |
| 167 |
| 188 |
| 95  |
| 86  |
| 165 |
| 186 |
+-----+
```

On the old server I get for the same queries:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.* FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title

+-----+----------------------
| ID  | Title
| 88  | AQA Biology Unit 1 
| 166 | AQA Biology Unit 2
| 187 | AQA Biology Unit 3
| 87  | AQA Chemistry Unit 1
| 167 | AQA Chemistry Unit 2
| 188 | AQA Chemistry Unit 3
| 95  | AQA FREE sample pac
| 86  | AQA Physics Unit 1
| 165 | AQA Physics Unit 2
| 186 | AQA Physics Unit 3
```

...and:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.ID FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title

+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 88  |
| 166 |
| 187 |
| 87  |
| 167 |
| 188 |
| 95  |
| 86  |
| 165 |
| 186 |
+-----+
```

So why would it be so weird on the new server? The **my.cnf** file (on the new server) looks like:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=200
max_user_connections=50
wait_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**UPDATE:** If I run the query from command line, I get an odd message:

```
mysql> SELECT glinks_Links.* FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title;
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

The weird thing is that the structure hasn't changed.. its still:

```
CREATE TABLE `glinks_Links` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `URL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkOwner` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `Add_Date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `Mod_Date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `Description` longtext,
  `Contact_Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Contact_Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hits` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isNew` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `isChanged` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `isPopular` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `isValidated` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Yes',
  `Rating` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Votes` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Date_Checked` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Timestmp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ExpiryDate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2147483647',
  `ExpiryCounted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ExpiryNotify` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_7` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_8` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_9` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_10` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_11` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_12` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_13` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_14` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_15` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_16` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_17` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_18` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_19` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_20` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isFreeDownload` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `powerpoint_file` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_slides` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_21` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_22` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_23` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_24` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_25` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_26` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_27` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_28` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_29` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_30` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_31` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_32` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_33` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_34` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_35` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_36` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_37` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_38` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_39` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_40` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_41` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_42` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_43` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_44` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_45` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_46` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_47` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_48` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_49` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_50` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_51` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_52` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_53` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_54` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_55` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_56` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_57` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_58` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_59` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_60` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_61` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_62` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_63` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_64` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_65` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_66` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_67` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_68` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_69` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_70` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_71` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_72` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_73` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_74` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_75` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_76` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_77` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_78` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_79` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_80` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_81` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_82` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_83` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_84` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_85` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_86` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_87` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_88` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_89` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_90` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_91` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_92` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_93` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_94` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_95` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_96` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_97` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_98` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_99` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_100` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_101` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_102` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_103` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_104` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_105` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_106` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_107` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_108` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_109` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_110` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_111` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_112` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_113` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_114` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_115` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_116` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_117` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_118` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_119` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_120` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_121` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_122` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_123` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_124` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_125` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_126` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_127` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_128` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_129` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_130` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_131` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_132` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_133` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_134` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_135` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_136` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_137` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_138` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_139` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_140` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_141` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_142` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_143` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_144` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_145` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_146` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_147` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_148` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `image_149` char(255) DEFAULT '',
  `CustomOrder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArticleType` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkExpired` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It's weird - as a basic SELECT on that table works fine:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.* FROM glinks_Links WHERE  glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes' ORDER BY Title LIMIT 100
```

**UPDATE 2:**

OK, so this is getting weirder!

```
SELECT glinks_Links.* FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title
```

This works. Yet this doesn't:

```
SELECT glinks_Links.* FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links WHERE glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND (glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17' AND glinks_Links.isValidated = 'Yes') ORDER BY Title
```

...so why would this bit cause it to fail?

```
glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = '17'
```

Comment: have you checked the MySQL bugs forum?

Comment: @Martin - I wouldn't have a clue what I'm looking for :)

Comment: here; [search here](https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=incorrect+row+count)

Comment: It sounds like a corrupt database to me!

Comment: When you upgraded from mysql 5.1 to mysql 5.7, did you `mysqldump` your data and run all the upgrade scripts?

Comment: @ebyrob - I did a mysqldump on the old server, and then imported it with `mysql -uXXX -pXXX DB_name < backup.sql` ... is there another step I should have taken?

Comment: @AndrewNewby I was just making sure...

Comment: Ok - I'm going to call it a day for now. 10pm and still can't get it going. Will have to do a bit more research tomorrow with a fresh mind :(

Comment: @AndrewNewby probably too late but you *are* still spose to run those upgrade scripts: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html#upgrade-methods  Also, you're not running the exact same queries or at least your tables have different names.

Comment: @AndrewNewby **stop.**  What are you using to *submit* this query?  `Your query returned 10 rows.` Is not a message that MySQL server or the standard client returns.  You're using something else on the client side, and *that* is what is broken.  What is it?  Also `mysql --version` does *not* give you any necessarily relevant information -- that's the version of the CLI, which will be the same only by coincidence. `mysql -e 'SELECT @@VERSION'` is the correct way to determine the running server version.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - this is in phpmyadmin. Weirdly, if I run it via command line (ssh), I get another odd error (see updated question above)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot interesting. I just updated phpmyadmin to 4.7, and it now correctly gives the BLOB error message.. but I'm not sure what it means

Comment: Why is your second table name just "l" in your SQL query?

Comment: @kojow7 - that wasn't actually what I posted. For some reason someone edited the question. I've put it back now, so you can see the proper SQL I'm using

Comment: @Strawberry Please be careful with your edits. :)

Comment: Everyone - I have put a demo phpmyadmin with the structure of those 2 tables in. I tried doing a SQLFiddle, but they limit you to 8000 bytes for some reason!

Answer (score 3):

Ah man - I can't believe it was just this! So, there were 2 problems:

1) I was using an older version of phpMyAdmin, so it was returning this error:

```
Your query returned 18446744073709551615 rows.
```

Instead of the proper error message of:

```
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

Upgrading the systems phpMyadmin fixed this.

2) I needed to edit **my.cnf**, as per:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77398

So now I have this for the [mysql] section:

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL

internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

The main difference being the last line.

It now runs perfectly, and gives the exact results I need. The issue seemed to be around the size of the table (it has almost 200 columns), and this was causing the max size issue I believe. Ideally I would re-write the whole database to store the images in another table, but it's a major job and as long as it works like this I'm happy (there are only a couple of hundred rows in the table)

Comment: glad you found it! I guess Tadman was right after all, it was PhpMyAdmin's fault! *shakes fist at PhpMyAdmin* `:-D`

Comment: @Martin - haha yeah! I have to admit, it didn't even occur to me to try upgrading that. It was just the vanilla install that comes with VestaCP, and is far newer than any I've used before - but I guess not new enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

**The Reason this number appears:**
The reason why you get this is because MySQL is casting the value -1 but it is unsigned so it can't be `<0` so instead it "wraps" and becomes that huge number.

> MySQL supports arithmetic with both signed and unsigned 64-bit values. If you are using numeric operators (such as + or -) and one of the operands is an unsigned integer, the result is unsigned by default (see Section 11.6.1, “Arithmetic Operators”). You can override this by using the SIGNED or UNSIGNED cast operator to cast a value to a signed or unsigned 64-bit integer, respectively.

[Read about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050671/3536236).

Also, [MySQL Bug Report on this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79295).

**Should this number appears as a result my Query?**
No, not as far as I can tell, this is possibly a bug in the way your columns are structured or your data is corrupted. Try [**repairing your tables**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html) and retry.

Comment: thanks, but that has lost me :) So is this a bug? Or do I need to change something in my table/SQL ?

Comment: This is undoubtedly the "second cause" but I think he'll still need a first cause.

Comment: There's no evidence, yet, to think that MySQL is for some reason casting a signed -1 to an unsigned integer, nor is there evidence, yet, to conclude that this is a bug in MySQL.  The bug report mentioned here is *clearly* not a bug -- the submitter doesn't understand the implications of one's complement -- this is exactly the correct result of this cast... and is in fact documented behavior.  [`mysql> SELECT CAST(1 - 2 AS UNSIGNED);`
        `-> 18446744073709551615`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this [casting signed to -1] is the only instance where this number is generated, as documented, I have not stated at any point that it is a MySQL bug. I referenced a bug report in the context of previous comments with the OP. I fully accept my answer is not a complete answer but it *does* explain what is causing this specific number in the row counts to appear. Cheers

Comment: If you're trying to explain the significance of this particular number (which admittedly has no intuitive meaning to the uninitiated), then, I see what you mean. 
 My issue was that you said *"MySQL is casting"* ...when it seemed apparent that MySQL had no reason to be doing it.  It was (as I suspected) a broken client program.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I was trying to articulate why this specific number was appearing when it makes no sense in the scope of the query given, I fully support that this doesn't even try to answer *Why* this casting is occuring. (which turned out to beig PhpMyAdmin versioning inconsistency in that program! Cheers.